# New React dev struggling with debouncing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debouncing

I've got a component that renders an input box. I've set up the change handler with a debounce call like so:

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
const changeHandler = (value) => {
  setSearchText(value);
  onStateChange({type: 'searchTextUpdated', value: value} )
};
const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback(debounce(changeHandler, 2000), []);
```

And the component is implemented like this:

```
<RequestSearchFilter   
   searchText={searchText}   
   onSearchFilterChange={debouncedChangeHandler} />
```

The problem is while the input box is "debouncing", the text being entered doesn't display at all. After the debounce wait time, the first couple of characters are missing. What could I be doing wrong here? Or is this to be expected?

I've tried to implement this at least a dozen ways, and this way seems to be the most accepted.

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new